# WebAPI return user items without session

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I just finished a starter course in WebAPI.

I went thru token validation.

I want to return a list of items that belong to a user.
The Action Method requires Authorization, but I do not want to use
a session to see the id of the user.  However I do not want to pass
the userID as a parameter in the Query from my Angular client.

This would allow another authenticated user to send the ID of a different
user to see their items.  I don't want this.

It seems like most WebAPI return results are for common items.

Comment: What token validation system are you using?

Comment: I am using 'Individual User Accounts' when I setup the WebAPI project. In Angular I send grant_type = "password"